# GraphDB - Ingesting from CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graphdb

I've just started using GraphDB and want to check this approach of ingesting documents from a CosmosDB.

So what I'm thinking is:

- Create JSON-LD from the CosmosDB document
- Convert that JSON-LD to RDF (using some library like https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js)
- Send a SPARQL `INSERT` query with RDF just created

Is this a general approach ok or is there something more simple I should be doing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GraphDB supports inserting of JSONLD files, that's why it isn't necessary to convert data into RDF. The only thing you need is to send JSON-LD document to RDF4J REST API.

You can look up some examples in GraphDB documentation. Useful links:

http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/loading-data.html
http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/devhub/workbench-rest-api/curl-commands.html